# How to distribute Apple Automator Workflow to other users

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a workflow that basically copies data from a specifically named USB (proof of concept at the moment) to a local folder. I would like to distribute this to other users since Automator seems to be per user. What is the optimal and safest way to distribute this where the user has to do as little as possible?

I have attempted to simply copy the workflow into the Folder Actions directory for another user, but that doesn't enable to folder actions automatically, so when plugging in the USB device, the workflow never runs. I also found a script within another post but that created folders on the Desktop and applied those actions there. I am trying to apply folder actions to /Volumes when a USB is mounted.

[image]

Script as of 5/25 @ 12:38 PM EST:

```
property TriggerFolder : "Volumes"
property attachFolderActionTo : (path to startup disk as text) & TriggerFolder

set resourceName to "USB Copy.workflow"
set PathToWorkflows to (path to workflows folder)
set PathToFolderActions to (PathToWorkflows as text) & "Applications:Folder Actions:"
set FolderActionScript to ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:" & resourceName) as string

tell application "Finder"
    if exists folder PathToFolderActions then
        error number -128
    else
        try
            set newfo to make new folder at PathToWorkflows with properties {name:"Applications"}
        end try
        delay 1.0
        try
            make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Folder Actions"}
        end try
    end if
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate file FolderActionScript to folder PathToFolderActions with replacing
end tell

tell application "Folder Actions Setup"
    activate
    try
        set addFolderAction to make new folder action with properties {name:TriggerFolder, path:attachFolderActionTo}
    end try
    try
        delay 0.5
        tell addFolderAction to make new script with properties {name:resourceName, path:(PathToFolderActions & resourceName)}
    end try
    if not folder actions enabled then
        set folder actions enabled to true
    end if
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: Original link I was working from:https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343258/how-to-deploy-automator-workflow-to-clients?newreg=a7ed6540cda84a449893b917a6cfcb9d

Comment: What have you tried so far?  From the script in that linked topic, the way to add the folder action is pretty much the same, just the names and paths would need to be changed.

Comment: I tried just copying and pasting my workflow into the location for another user. That doesn't actually do anything when I plugged in the test USB. I also tried modifying that script to include /Volumes but I wasn't quite sure how to use that path since that is the path. I kept getting /Volumes and Volumes folders on my desktop along with a popup to enable folder actions on Volumes. I have also added a photo of my workflow that I would like to distribute to others and get working as simply as possible.

Comment: If you want the workflow to be triggered by Folder Actions, then Folder Actions needs to be configured. Just copying it to the FA folder doesn't set up an action. I don't know if it's possible to automate that.

Comment: @benwiggy I guess the automation of the folder actions configuration is what I am looking for. Not sure if it's better to do this workflow as a full fledged Python script or something similar.

Comment: The Run AppleScript action is passing 'input' to the next action. Then you're getting the disk, but ignoring the input of that action -- so that action does nothing.

Comment: @benwiggy the workflow works as intended, just not when copied to another users directories.

Comment: The folder action is already passed the items added to the watched folder, so all you need to do is check for the name of an item, and if it is what you are looking for then pass the item on.  It might be easier to use an AppleScript that contains the folder action, then the script could be run by the user to relocate itself and configure the folder action, after which the folder action handler in the script does its thing.

Comment: You might have seen my answer on the page linked to in the first comment (also: [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343586/266364)).  It's pretty much a set up script for Folder Actions that allows you to enable, create, and assign folder actions that operate on a folder.  The whole process is AppleScript-based, which will be simpler to implement and distribute than an Automator workflow.

Comment: @CJK I was trying to follow that script and modify it for my needs, but it kept creating a Volumes folder on the desktop and a popup about enabling folder actions. Not sure if thats intended, but end users will not know what the popup is for and would create an issue for them.

Comment: @madknacker No, those things are specific to however you adapted the script for yourself.  It doesn't do either of those things by itself—for instance, there's no line in that script that will create any folder anywhere on your hard drive, not even on the desktop, so whatever changes you made are responsible.  I'll see if I have time later to adapt a version of the script for whatever it is you're trying to do.  If you're able, a really clear, specific description of what you're trying to achieve would be good. Your current question as written is extremely vague.

Comment: @CJK I added my current script above that seems to be working if a new user runs it. I couldn't figure out how to check for the subfolder "Folder Actions" and create a tree of folders, so they're done individually. Any suggestions on cleaning it up are much appreciated.